# The code is about structs nodes and it is printing address

Tags: c, struct, warnings

When I want him to print the second number (I asked him in the main function when I wrote list1->next->content ), the code prints an address and at the end doesn't return 0!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct cell* Cellptr;
typedef struct cell
    {
    int content;
    Cellptr next;
}Cell;

Cellptr scanning(int);
void freeing(Cellptr);
int main()
{
    Cellptr list1=NULL;
    int x;
    printf("Please enter how many nodes do you want:\n");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    scanning(x, list1);
    printf("the second number is %d", list1->next->content);
    freeing(list1);
return 0;
}
Cellptr scanning(int num)
{
    int i;
    Cellptr first=list1;
    for(i=0; i<num; i++)
    {
        if(NULL==(first=(Cellptr)malloc(sizeof(Cell))))
        {
            printf("Illegal Input");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("the value for the %d\n", i);
        scanf("%d", &first->content);
        first=first->next;
    }
return first;
}
void freeing(Cellptr body1)
{
    if(body1==NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    freeing(body1->next);
    free(body1);
}
```

its a simple code where we give numbers and then print one of them

Comment: This is useless in all but the last iterations of the loop: `first=first->next;` In all other iterations the value of `first` is thrown away immediately and replaced by a new block of memory returned by `malloc`. Also `first->next` is uninitialized anyway.

Comment: Where did you get the idea for a recursive function to free a list? That is not a typical problem where recursion is recommended.

Comment: Ok if 'first' is being thrown away what is the problem? That's why I made a new the struct made instead of using struct list1? Sorry for not understanding your answer, I am beginner in programming.

Comment: If you do not keep any pointers to your allocated memory, you cannot access them. Especially you do not get a linked list in the end.